# Abnormal Workbench Condition on calling showView Method

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am getting `PartInitException`:

> Abnormal Workbench Condition

when I am trying to call the showView method for my plugin view.

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        IWorkbenchWindow iw = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        try {
            view = (ReporterView) iw.getActivePage().showView("com.he.reportLayer.views.ReporterView");
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

This was working earlier and have no idea why this is not now.
I have tried setting `IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE` and `IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_CREATE` but I get the same exception.

Full stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Abnormal Workbench Condition
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4222)
    at com.he.reportLayer.views.ReportCreator$2.run(ReportCreator.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: Show us the full stack trace

Comment: To me this looks like a bug in Platform/UI. What version do you use? Can you debug and see what the `result` array holds when reaching line 4222?

Comment: Using this version :Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers

Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

Comment: Sorry, I meant the version of the Eclipse SDK you are using, i.e. the one that your target platform references. And again: what does the `result` array hold?